# Php from database to xml

Tags: php, xml

I try to export data from database to XML. My code is below:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
require_once 'DataBase.php';
$db=new DataBase();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");
$db->execute();
$arr = $db->resultset();
header("Content-type: text/xml");
foreach ($arr as $row){
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
$newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
$newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

But when I run my PHP file I get empty window ( and don't get any error) . My array is not empty, I checked it. 
What is wrong there? How can I solve it?

I check that it works in Chrome and doesn't work in Mozilla browser ...

Comment: You said that it works in Chrome but not in Firefox ?

Comment: Yes, In Chrome I see xml text , in Firefox - not

Comment: Is your firefox up to date ?

Comment: View Source, and there it goes...

Comment: Your code works great in Firefox too. I'd just test it. Maybe the problem is somewhere else ?

Comment: It's a common (I think) problem. I have faced it many times in the past, however, it didn't affect the functionality of my app since I was finally saving it as an xml file.  As @ThW mentioned in his answer if you check the developer tools of your browser XML content should be there.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the content type header is not recognized by FF in your case. That means the output is rendered as HTML - not XML. Read as HTML it only contains of some unknown tags with attributes - nothing to show.

Use the developer tools of your browser. From there check that the response content is the XML you expected and the response headers are correct.

It should allow you to find the reason for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my sample implementation, it works with firefox and with chrome but it uses simplexml instead of dom.

Also the sql was modified as "where 1" did not make much sense to me ;)

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><markers></markers>');

    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbname = 'testdb';
    $db = 'pgsql';

     $db = new PDO($db . ':host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $pass);

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM markers ");

  $arr = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 header("Content-type: text/xml");

foreach ($arr as $row){
$newnode = $xml->addChild("marker");
$newnode->addAttribute("name",$row['name']);
$newnode->addAttribute("address", $row['address']);
$newnode->addAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->addAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
$newnode->addAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}   

echo $xml ->asXML();
```

Here is the result in Firefox and in Chrome and the test data i've used:

test data:
[image]
chrome:
[image]
firefox:
[image]